# React Router not linking to page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Fairly new to react and trying to get the router to work for me.  I'm pulling in data from a third party api using a simple form.  When the data is retrieved I'd like to display it in a new route, and then ultimately have another route for each item retrieved.  When I submit the form I just get a '?' in the route params.  If I enter the route manually then submit the form the data displays.  How can I get the data to display on form submit?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import RecipeList from "./RecipeList";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const APP_ID = "XXXXXXXX";
  const APP_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const res = await axios(url);
    const data = await res.data.hits;
    console.log(data);
    setRecipes(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [query]);

  const updateSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    console.log(search);
  };

  const getSearchQuery = () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
    setSearch("");
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <form className="search-form" onSubmit={getSearchQuery}>
            <input
              className="search-input"
              type="text"
              value={search}
              onChange={updateSearch}
              placeholder="search by food name"
            />
            <button className="search-button" type="submit">
              Search Recipes
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* <RecipeList recipes={recipes}/> */}
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/recipes" element={<RecipeList recipes={recipes}/>} />
          <Route path="/recipes/:id" />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const RecipeList = ({ recipes }) => {
  console.log(recipes);
  return (
    <div>
      {recipes.map(({ recipe }, id) => (
        <Link to={`recipes/${recipe.label}`}>
          <p key={id}>{recipe.label}</p>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecipeList;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "enter the route manually then submit the form the data displays" means? Are you not navigating to "/recipes", then entering and submitting the form data via the UI? Are you saying the GET request is only `"https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?"`? without the query string params? Question/issue is unclear.

Comment: I just meant that when i type '/recipes' in the url and then submit the form the data displays.  When I submit the form on the '/' route nothing happens.

Comment: Well, you're not rendering any route content on a `"/"` path so I wouldn't expect anything to render other than the form. Are you wanting to render the form and the data on the `"/"` path, and the specific recipes on a `"/recipeId"` path? In other words, unnesting the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question/issue you are having issue linking to a specific recipe. I suspect it is because you are using a relative link, so you are linking to a `"/recipes/recipes/<label"`.

Either use absolute link paths, i.e. using a leading `"/"`:

```
<Link to={`/recipes/${recipe.label}`}>
  <p key={id}>{recipe.label}</p>
</Link>
```

Or use a correct relative path, i.e. only append the next level path segment, in other words, appending `recipe.label` to "/recipes":

```
<Link to={`${recipe.label}`}>
  <p key={id}>{recipe.label}</p>
</Link>
```

If you wanting to start on `"/"` and submit the form and navigate to `"/recipes"` then issue an imperative navigation after submitting the form. Import the `useNavigate` hook to issue the imperative navigation and move the `Router` to wrap the `App` component so the routing context is provided to it and the `useNavigate` hook can work properly.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import RecipeList from "./RecipeList";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- use navigate hook

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const APP_ID = "XXXXXXXX";
  const APP_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const res = await axios(url);
    const data = await res.data.hits;
    console.log(data);
    setRecipes(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [query]);

  const updateSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    console.log(search);
  };

  const getSearchQuery = () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
    setSearch("");
    navigate("/recipes"); // <-- imperative navigation
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <form className="search-form" onSubmit={getSearchQuery}>
            <input
              className="search-input"
              type="text"
              value={search}
              onChange={updateSearch}
              placeholder="search by food name"
            />
            <button className="search-button" type="submit">
              Search Recipes
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/recipes" element={<RecipeList recipes={recipes}/>} />
        <Route path="/recipes/:id" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Comment: Oh yes, you caught that as well.  However the initial problem remains that the data still doesn't display when I submit the form.  When I type in a query in the form input (at localhost:3000), I'm expecting the data to display in a new route (localhost:3000/recipes).  That's what I'm currently trying to work out.

Comment: @RRhodes Ok, so you are on `"/"` and submit the form, and you want the path to now be `"/recipes"`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I'd like the form to be on every page so the user can keep searching, but I want the results to display on '/recipes'.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @RRhodes Ok, I think I understand now. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Trying to make this work - keep getting this error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Comment: @RRhodes Ah, move the `Router` so it wraps the `App` component. See updated answer.